# Server 2008 locks me out when not using the machine for 10 minutes after installing SP2

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have recently installed Service Pack 2 on my Windows Server 2008 machine (which I use actively for development, and i'm always logged on to).

Now, after this installation, when I don't use the machine for some time (let's say, 10 minutes), it locks itself so I have to press Ctrl+Alt+Del and log back in.

I have already checked the Screen Saver settings, and it's "None", as it always has been. I also looked into power settings and everything looks right (20 mins to turn off monitor, and i haven't found any settings regarding locking me in there).

Do you have any idea what I can do so that it won't lock me out after not using the machine for a while?

Thanks!
Daniel

Comment: You might have better luck with this at serverfault.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way for me to move it (like you guys can if you close it?)

Comment: i'd leave it open here, some powerusers may run into a similar issue using Server2k8-as-Workstation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the group policy for your account.

- type `gpedit.msc` into the start search box and hit enter
- navigate to User configuration -> Administrative templates -> control panel -> display
- Change `screen saver` to disabled, and `screen saver timeout` to a high value just in case.

Comment: I don't have `screen saver` as an option. But the gpedit solution below worked for me - I set the idle time to 99999 minutes, which effectively disables it.

Comment: @BobDoolittle at time of writing, all the answers here use gpedit.  But yeah, Screen Saver is missing for me too.

Answer (score 10):

What worked for me, was similar to the above...

In gpedit, navigate to Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options -> Microsoft network server: Amount of idle time required before suspending a session

then reset the timeout to the desired value in minutes.

Comment: Any idea how [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"DisableLockWorkstation"=dword:00000001 is connected to this ?

Comment: And "Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options -> Microsoft network server:Disconnect clients when logon hours expire" also sounds related. Is it related ?

Comment: The solution worked. For those who reach here for "lock" related issues after overcoming screen saver issues this is the one answer that helped. Thankyou * 1000

Comment: "Microsoft network server: Amount of idle time required before suspending a session" - For this policy setting, a value of 0 means to disconnect an idle session as quickly as is reasonably possible. The maximum value is 99999, which is 208 days; in effect, this value disables the policy

Answer (score 0):

Even better than another answer: in the same area under (microsoft server), select disable the cntl alt del requirement for login. Then set time out to 99999 to be safe.

"In gpedit, navigate to Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options -> Microsoft network server: Amount of idle time required before suspending a session"

Then reset the timeout to the desired value in minutes.